# Input string was not in a correct format when affecting longitude,lattitude to a Location

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, bing-maps

I am following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2012/11/05/getting-started-with-bing-maps-windows-store-apps-native/) to add icones to every Location in a map according to its longitude and latitude from this web Service:(json format)

```
{
success: 1,
total: 2,
locals: [
{
id_local: "59",
local_longi: "20",
local_latit: "25894"
},
{
id_local: "60",
local_longi: "10.33699",
local_latit: "25.997745"
}
]
}
```

this is my code:

```
private async void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            await
                        this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(
async () =>
                        {
                    UriS = "MyURL";
                    var http = new HttpClient();
                   http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize =Int32.MaxValue;
                   var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriS);
                   var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);

                 for(int i=0;i< int.Parse(rootObject.total); i++)
                   {
                  //Get the current location
                   Location[] location = new Location[2];
                   location[i] = new Location(double.Parse(rootObject.locals[i].local_latit), double.Parse(rootObject.locals[i].local_longi));  //I get the error here

                    //Update the position of the GPS pushpin
                    MapLayer.SetPosition(GpsIcon, location[i]);

                    //Set the radius of the Accuracy Circle
               GpsIcon.SetRadius(args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy);                 

                            //Make GPS pushpin visible
                            GpsIcon.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

                            //Update the map view to the current GPS location
                            MyMap.SetView(location[i], 17);

                            }
                        }));
        }
```

I get this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

at this line:

```
location[i] = new Location(double.Parse(rootObject.locals[i].local_latit), double.Parse(rootObject.locals[i].local_longi));
```

if this Helps,this is the result of Debugging:

[image]

so please how can I correct my code,to put icon according to its Location
thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little digging on MSDN.  Try this:

```
location[i] = new Location(
    double.Parse(
        rootObject.locals[i].local_latit,
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float
    ), 
    double.Parse(
        rootObject.locals[i].local_longi,
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float
    )
);
```

Here's the MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I have resolved this error by transforming my variables to doubles from the model class :)

Answer (score 2):

Debug and check what `rootObject.locals[i].local_latit` and `rootObject.locals[i].local_longi` are at the error. If they end up being null instead of declared strings it would throw this error.

Comment: thanks LeChosenOne for your reply,but when debugging I have verifried that rootObject.locals[i].local_latit and rootObject.locals[i].local_longi containe the string values